# Type checking to perform a variation of the strategy pattern

Tags: c#

So, consider the following code:

```
public class OneConcreteTypeOfOutputFormat 
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IEntityWriter> writers;
    public Dispatcher()
    {
        this.writers = new Dictionary<string, IEntityWriter();
        CreateWriters(writers);
    }

    private void CreateWriters(Dictionary<string, IEntityWriter> writers)
    {
        string nspace = typeof(OneConcreteWriter).Namespace;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (var writer in assembly.GetAllFromNamespace<IEntityWriter>(nspace))
            writers.Add(writer.EntityType.FullName, writer);
    }

    private bool HasWriterForAllPropTypes(IEnumerable<Entity> data)
    {
        return data.All(ent => writers.ContainsKey(ent.GetType().FullName));
    }

    public void WriteEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities)
    {
         Require.That(() => HasWriterForAllPropTypes(outputData));
         foreach(Entity entity in entities)
             writers[entity.GetType().FullName].Write(entity);
    }
}
```

Here, I am using the actual type of the Entity (which is a baseclass) to write it. I've heard that it's considered inelegant to use type-checking to perform operations, but I really don't want each Entity to write itself. This is a very easy and comfortable way to match something like this up. Do you find this clashing with the tenets of object-oriented programming? Sadly, each writer need to cast to it's specific type in the Write method.

**UPDATE**

Note that the code above is completely updated - changes include:

- Added writer initialization code. It is delegated to a unit-tested extension method.
- Changed the name of the class to reflect that it is only one of different types of output formats - so it would require more than just creating one writer for each Entity.
- Added a little bit of the validation code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it will be useful for you, but here is one variant:
Add to your Entity base class a method called GetWriter. This method should return IEntityWriter.
This IEntityWriter should have method Write() without parameters.

Then an implementation of an Entity would be something like:

```
class XXXEntity: Entity
{
   public override IEntityWriter GetWriter()
   {
      return new XXXEntityWriter(this);
   }
}
```

And then the method WriteEntities in your example would be

```
public void WriteEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities)
{
   foreach(Entity entity in entities)
      entity.GetWriter().Write();
}
```

The 'mappings' approach (no matter if it is in the code or in the xml file) have a couple of problems:
1. It's easy to do wrong configuration of mappings. You can map a XXXEntity to YYYEntityWriter.
2. It's easy to forget to add an EntityWriter when you add new Entity or you can forget to add the mapping. And this is a real problem.

By the way. Judging from the description of the task, a concrete EntityWriter have to know about a concrete Entity.
So mapping is not as flexible as it seems, because of this explicit connection between EntityWriter and Entity.
It's not a problem to use GetType(). The problem here is to separate (hide) connections between classes that should work together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this is indeed one idea, thanks. Mappings approach: Actually, I simplified the code above a bit - in reality IEntityWriter has a property GetEntityType, which is used to put them in the map, and the Writers are dynamically instantiated using reflection. Will consider it a bit more, thanks :)

Comment: +1: Scrap 'problem' 1 though, it's not like using your suggestion makes it less likely to match the wrong writer.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: Actually, it is. In my approach, if you create a concrete EntityWriter it will work with a concrete Entity. So if you create XXXEntityWriter it will work with XXXEntity only. And every time you create a concrete Entity, you'll have to create a corresponding EntityWriter for this Entity.

Comment: @Max you really want to do it this way. This is the correct design approach.. Even if there's reflection instantiation, put that code in the individual concrete classes to reflection instantiate the correct writer on each individual entity basis. Make a base class that will do the common reflection code if you care (or use a proper DI framework instead) and each implementor class will utilize that common reflection code to get the writer *it* wants

Comment: @Jimmy Separation of concern was what I was going for - if each Entity should know how to write itself, then the same can be said for alot more. Another problem that I havn't clarified is that there will be different *types* of writers - dammit, I've asked this question all wrong - let me update it with a bit more real code.

Comment: Now, the task is more clear. I think that it can not be resolved by means of pure OOP. You'll have to use the reflection in one way or another and your solution is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you have words "strategy pattern" in your subject, but what you want is called "polymorphic behavior". There are 2 ways that considered fine:

1. Adding required interface method to Entity and overriding/implementing it in all descendants.
2. Using Visitor design pattern. The idea is almost the same as in p.1, but in this case it would be quite easy to add more methods like `Write()` without need of changing interface `Entity` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Described solutions are really nice, but sometimes you just don't want Entity class to know anything about EntityWriter. Moreover, sometimes it might even be impossible if these classes are put in a different assemblies. And the only thing you need is a mapping table in a client class (Dispatcher) of which EntityWriter to use based on Entity type.

The only bad thing I can see in your code is that Dispatcher knows about all possible types of Entity and EntityWriter. I don't see any problems with using GetType () or typeof in my code. But it is surely better to get rid of specific classes from the Dispatcher code.

The simplest thing is to use a little bit of reflection and Activator class:

1. Create an xml file that contains mapping of entity types to writer types
2. Create IDictionary field in Dispatcher and fill it with the data from xml file on startup where Entity writer instance is got by using Activator class
3. On the runtime just use the same code as you have in WriteEntries, but change the signature to get entity type FullName: entity.GetType().FullName

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually, this is what I am doing (but instead of using an XML file, I get all writers from their specific namespace). I wanted to simplify the code before I posted, but as usual that is not a good idea. Thanks for coming up with the same solution though, makes me a bit more secure if I end up choosing this one! :)

Comment: I disagree, when reflection is necessitated by the design to maintain loose coupling, you may want to take a step back from the design- or rely on some late binding or proxy framework (i.e. ninject, MEF, WCF) that abstracts this in an industry standard way.

Comment: Afaik, Ninject, MEF and WCF will allow you to create an instance of an interface, but there is no way to instruct them which specific class should be instantiated based on a provided instance of Entity at the runtime. I highly agree that we should use standart proxy frameworks, but I can't see how they will help in that case. Can you elaborate your solution?